# Save MediaPlayer State

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm currently working on an Music Player and now I want to save on which song and position the mediaplayer stopped. The songs are stored in my assets folder and i read them into a list. I came up with the idea to write the index of the song and the position into an `.xml` or an `.json`, but I wanted to know if there's a better way to save the data?

Comment: if you want to store only song index and position, you can use datastore

Comment: You should use datastore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try it in any media player but you can use shared preferences in kotlin and java it is useful for using key-value data if you will store just a small information you can store it in shared preferences https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

I hope this link will help you.

Comment: SharedPrefs are somewhat deprecated and would be deprecated in near future, You should use datastore instead. Here codelab's tutorial on it  https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-preferences-datastore

Comment: you might be right i did not know  datastore i am kinda beginner in android but i use shared preferences easily in my basic projects that's why i suggested it

Comment: If you use kotlin for your projects, you should try using datastore it's easy and a lot better than  shared prefs

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick answer. It's working perfect.